# Page Control Through Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uipagecontrol

I am interested in using a page control to switch through entries in my array without changing the view. How can I do this? Is there a tutorial. . .

However, whenever the pages is switched, the background color and some images change. Is there any way to run code once a page is switched?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIPageControl` only *represents* paging, it does not manage the paging behavior itself. You will need to write your own code to iterate through your array when clicking on the `UIPageControl`.  The `currentPage` property should be set to the index you are working with in your array, the `totalPages` property should be set to the array's `count` property.  Finally, you'll need to setup a target/action pair for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event using [`-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW4)

```
[pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The [documentation states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> When a user taps a page control to move to the next or previous page, the control sends the **UIControlEventValueChanged** event for handling by the delegate. The delegate can then evaluate the currentPage property to determine the page to display. The page control advances only one page in either direction.

So you can use that event to determine when a page is changed.

Example:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *items;
```

[...]

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine",@"Ten", nil];
    [self.pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Left Swipe to go to previous page
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(previousPage:)];
    leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];

    // Right Swipe to go to next page
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(nextPage:)];
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];

}

- (void)previousPage:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer
{
    self.pageControl.currentPage = self.pageControl.currentPage-1;
}

- (void)nextPage:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer
{
    self.pageControl.currentPage = self.pageControl.currentPage+1;
}

- (void)pageChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSString *selectedItem = [self.items objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage];
    NSLog(@"\nSelected Item: %@\nCurrent Page: %d\nTotal Number of Pages: %d\n", selectedItem, self.pageControl.currentPage+1, self.pageControl.numberOfPages);
}
```

When you click the page control, it moves forward or backward through the array of strings represented by the `self.items` property. `-pageChanged:` is where you would update the controls on the view as well.

If you want to update the current page in the UIPageControl in another area, simply do:

```
self.pageControl.currentPage = 5;  // set to whatever page you need represented
```

Comment: Can you please explain some more with code examples, it is the first time I am using a page control.

Comment: Ok, The NSLog does not appear and is your code going to actually change the row? If so, does the code to display the Array to a label need to reload?

Comment: If the `NSLog()` statement isn't being called, the `-pageChanged:` method isn't being called which means `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` isn't being set on your `UIPageControl`. The code does not change the elements in the array, it reads the current element that the `currentPage` property of the `UIPageControl` represents.  You need to make sure that `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is called in `-viewDidLoad:` or `-viewWillAppear:`.  To display the array contents in a `UILabel` you need to simply set the `text` property on the label inside the `-pageChanged:` method.

Comment: Why do you create a new page control named aPageControl? Also, My code is made up of objects using Keys. Would This code work: `    NSString *selectedItem = [[self.records objectAtIndex:aPageControl.currentPage] valueForKey:@"name"];
` Lastly, pageChanged gets called when the screen is swiped?

Comment: It is not necessary to create the `aPagedControl` variable, it's just demonstrating what `sender` is.  No, `UIPageControl` is purely visual.  To have `pageChanged:` when the screen is swiped you need to use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and attach it to the view you are swiping and set the same `target` and `action` on it.  Yes, if `self.records` is an array of objects and `name` is an `NSString *` property on those objects, `selectedItem` should contain the name property.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!! Now, how can I swipe anywhere on the screen for it to switch because, I have to swipe directly on the page control for it to swipe?? Thanks for all your help

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of setting up swipe gesture recognizers on the view controller's view. You'll need one gesture recognizer for each direction.  If you want multiple touches required (e.g. 2 finger swipe), you'll have to setup separate recognizer objects for those as well.

Comment: Do I need to connect anything in Interface Builder? Do I also need to keep pageChanged: code? I get the error: `[MainViewController pageLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19a600
2011-11-01 21:16:07.569 iBehave[9425:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController pageLeft:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19a600'
`

Comment: That error means there is no `-pageLeft:` method in your `MainViewController`.  Yes, you'll have to keep the `-pageChanged:` code except for the `NSLog()` statement.  When the `UIPageControl` has it's `currentPage` property changed, it updates it's own video (the dots) and `-pageChanged:` is called because of the `-addTarget:forAction:` method. The `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` objects change the `currentPage` property on the `UIPageControl`, which in turn calls `-pageChanged:`, which updates your `UILabel`.  All these objects work together to accomplish swiping and page control.

Comment: I keep on getting an error about pageLeft:(Unrecognized selector)! What is pageLeft? I do not use it in any way??!!

Comment: You likely have `@selector(pageLeft:)` used somewhere that needs to be replaced with the proper method name. That error means your code is sending the `pageLeft:` message somewhere. It may be setup as an IBAction in a XIB file.

Comment: It Does Not Work? 1) What Do I Need To Connect In Interface Builder? 2) Do I Need This:`- (void)nextPage:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer` or This: `- (void)nextPage:(id)sender`?